# How do I make django replace spaces in urls with underscores automatically?

Tags: python, django, url

I'm using Django to build a site. I'd like to have my urls look like: `example.com/product/product_name_goes_here`, with underscores separating the words in the name. In the database, some product names have spaces in them, so urls currently look like `example.com/product/product name goes here`. Everything works fine, but I'd like to not have spaces in my urls.

The recommended ways to do this seem to rely on placing that knowledge in a lot of places in the code. So `urls.py` would contain something like this:

```
url(r'^product/(?P<product_name>.+)$', views.product)
```

And then, `views.py` would contain:

```
def product(request, product_name):
    real_product_name = product_name.replace("_", " ")
    #do things with real_product_name
```

If I need to do a [reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) of a url, I need to do the following:

```
url = reverse(myapp.views.product, product.name.replace(" ", "_"))
```

And in templates, I will have to [write a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)[1] to replace spaces with underscores, then include the url as follows:

```
{% url myapp.views.product product.name|spaces_to_underscores %}
```

This would all work fine, except it's very error-prone. If I forget, *once*, that I need to do this, I'll have a bad url, or a view that breaks.

Is there a way to tell the Django url dispatcher that I always want spaces in the product name part of the url[2] to be underscores? That way, I could do reverse url lookups with only the product name, and it would automatically replace spaces with underscores, I wouldn't have to use any filters in my `{% url %}` tags in templates, and I wouldn't have to remember in each view function to replace underscores with spaces.

[1] I know about [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slugify). It doesn't help here; I don't want dashes, and in addition, I'd still have to *remember* to use it everywhere.

[2] A slightly less preferable way to do this would be if *all* spaces in the url were changed to underscores. It would work with my current site design, but I'd rather only change spaces in the product name.

Comment: I know you *know* about slugify but I would recommend revisiting it ... also change your model to have a slug field (that is automagically created on model creation) and use that for your urls and your lookups ...

Comment: Good comment Joran. It's indeed wise to maintain a different slug-table in your application. Slugs are unique and need to be reserved in some way. I've had enough situations where different fashion collections (clothes) had the same product name over different seasons, so slugifying is very unsafe. You will want to reserve each slug for each product and, when needed, add some suffix/preffix to your slug when you have a naming collision. Finally; if you work with more developers your method will fail almost for sure. If someone doesnt know what you did, it will surely bug.